# Is it possible to use FactoryGirl without Rails?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I'm creating a GUI application which interacts with database so I need fixture management for my RSpec tests. I use sqlite database and am going to write a class which will manipulate data with straight SQL. I need to test it's database interaction functionality.

I couldn't find any libraries which could do 2 basic things when I run RSpec tests:

1. Clear database or particular tables in it
2. Load specific data into it so I can use that data in my tests

There are already ten thousands of blog posts and manuals which clearly explain how to use FactoryGirl with any version of Rails but no one **without** it. I started digging around and this is what I have (note that I don't use rails and it's components):

`spec/note_spec.rb:`

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'note'

describe Note do
  it "should return body" do
    @note = Factory(:note)
    note.body.should == 'body of a note'
  end
end
```

`spec/factories.rb:`

```
Factory.define :note do |f|
  f.body 'body of a note'
  f.title 'title of a note'
end
```

`lib/note.rb:`

```
class Note
  attr_accessor :title, :body
end
```

When I run `rspec -c spec/note_spec.rb` I get following:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Note should return body
     Failure/Error: @note = Factory(:note)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `save!' for #<Note:0x8c33f18>
     # ./spec/note_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible at all to use FactoryGirl without Rails and Rails libraries like ActiveModel/ActiveRecord?
2. Do I have to subclass my `Note` class from particular class, since FactoryGirl is looking for `save!` method?
3. Are there any other more viable solutions besides FactoryGirl?

I'm totally new to Ruby/RSpec/BDD, so any help will be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default factory_girl creates saved instances. If you don't want to save the object to the database, you can create unsaved instances using the `build` method.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'note'

describe Note do
  it "should return body" do
    @note = Factory.build(:note)
    note.body.should == 'body of a note'
  end
end
```

See "Using Factories" in the [Getting Started file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

Comment: Yes, `build` seems to work. So FG expects from my class to implement `save!` method?

Comment: This is correct; see the [documentation for `create`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/1.3.3/Factory#create-class_method).

Comment: What would you do for associations?

Comment: @LeoRomanovsky Within factories, you can use factory_girl's DLS to generate associated data. See [Lazy Attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes) and [Associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) in the guide.